# How to start and stop jboss from apache ant build.xml file targets

Tags: ant, jboss

I have make build.xml 
make master build.xml and make jar war ear files

now i want to stop and start jboss server from master build.xml file using apache ant

then copy all war and ear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop jboss remotely (which I assume is what you want) from the command line as shown [here](http://goo.gl/mUytc)
Locally, that is if your run the build-file on the same machine as your jboss is running, you can easily do this with ants `exec` command

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

```
<!-- Start Jboss -->
<target name="start-jboss" description="Starts back-end EJB container" depends="prepare">
    <exec executable="${jboss.bin.dir}/run.bat" spawn="false">
    </exec>
    <copy todir="destination of where you want the file to go" overwrite="true">
       <fileset file="myfile.war" />
       <fileset file="myfile.ear" />
    </copy>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>| J B O S S   S T A R T E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
</target>

<!-- Stop Jboss -->
<target name="stop-jboss" description="Stops back-end EJB container" depends="prepare">
    <exec executable="${jboss.bin.dir}/shutdown.bat" spawn="false">
        <arg line="-S" />
    </exec>
            <copy todir="destination to where you want the file to go" overwrite="true">
            <fileset file="myfile.war" />
            <fileset file="myfile.ear" />
            </copy>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>
    <echo>| J B O S S   S T O P P E D   |</echo>
    <echo>+-----------------------------+</echo>

</target>
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Don't think that will work. Spawn needs to be true for the next commands to fire i think.

Comment: @Nicolas DiPiazza - Having spawn true/false is that it shows/not show the stack trace on command line console. It has nothing do to with next command firing or not. The code works fine mate. If you have any error then let me know. :)

Comment: might be that jboss as7 is a bit different... but in my build.xml script I was using... i started up 3 jboss instances at the same time. without spawn=true, the first jboss instance would fire and then steal the flow until it was stopped... of which wouldn't happen of course.

Comment: @Nicolas DiPiazza - OK remove the depends="prepare" elemnt and then re-run the build.